# 401 Unauthorized when authenticating with token in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a Django project where users are required to verify their phone number on their first login. Once their phone number is verified, a token is assigned to them. However, when I try to authenticate with the token in my tests, I get a 401 unauthorized error.

Does anyone know where the problem might be?

`r = client.patch("/user/", data= dict(pk=1), format='json', headers= dict(Authorization=f"Token {user.auth_token.key}")) assert r.status_code == 200`

Comment: could you share more details about how you authenticate the token? Do you use any packages? what is the structure of the token?

Comment: I'm really confused and I really need help urgently. I generate the token with a signal in models.py:
 
 ```@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Token.objects.create(user=instance)```

And then I return the token to the user with a Response, and in my tests I format the token like this:

```token = {Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b}```
And I send it like this:

```client.patch(url, data, headers=token)```

Comment: Do you create a token for each save on the user instance? how do you authenticate this token? what is your backend authenticator in drf settings?